# Getting data in url printing in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

i am getting data through Url then split and displayed in java script but i am not able to print in html page please help me

### Page 1

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function setURL() {
        var dt_value = document.getElementById("dt_id").value;
        //just test here ..what is coming..
        alert( dt_value );
        var sjdurl =  "page2.html?Name=" + dt_value;
        popup = window.open(sjdurl);
        popup.window.moveTo(950,150); 

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align:left; margin:8px 5px auto;">
       <label for="dt_id">Please enter a date and time </label>
       <input type="Text" id="dt_id" maxlength="25" size="25"/>
       <input type='button' onclick='setURL()' value='SUBMIT'>     
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

### page2

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
     window.onload=getParams
     function getParams() {
         var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
         var params = new Array();
         if ( idx != -1 ) {
             var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
             for ( var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++ ) {
                 nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
                 params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
             }
         }
         return params;
     }
     params = getParams();
     firstname = unescape( params["Name"] );
     document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = firstname;
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input type="text" id="d" value="">
  </body>
  </html>
```

if i print first name using document.write(); it working fine but not able print same in html text box

### Note :

we wont change the java script to body it must be present inside  and text field must present inside the body tag.  is it possible???

Comment: you need to use .value instead of  .innerHTML document.getElementById("d").value=firstname;

Comment: i tried that also its not working Ashok

Comment: can you put alert(firstname); and check if the value coming in alert

Comment: yes that is working fine inside java script block

Comment: Try with changing the id of text field instead of `"d"` and give the same in `document.getElementById()` and use `.value` instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Typical example of how people don't care about proper placement of script tags,. You should use the below code:

```
</head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" id="d" value="">
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  window.onload=getParams
  function getParams()
   {
   var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
   var params = new Array();
   if (idx != -1) 
   {
   var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
   for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++)
   {
    nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
    params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
   }
   }
return params;
 }
  params = getParams();
  firstname = unescape(params["Name"]);
  document.getElementById("d").innerHTML=firstname;
  </script>
  </body>
```

The reason is simple. the time you call `document.getElementById("d").innerHTML=firstname;`

it simple isn't availble in  DOM so you need to move your script below the markup to make it available for JS to process.

Answer (score 0):

Same as the above answer but minor changes.

```
</head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" id="d" value="" />
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  window.onload=getParams
  function getParams()
   {
   var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
   var params = new Array();
   if (idx != -1) 
   {
   var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
   for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++)
   {
    nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
    params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
   }
   }
return params;
 }
  params = getParams();
  firstname = unescape(params["Name"]);
  document.getElementById("d").value=firstname;
  </script>
  </body>
```

Don't set input.innerHTML; instead set "value".

Comment: If you want script in head, add an event listener for window.onload, on which you perform document.getElementById("d").value=firstname;